# Bypass function return value requirement F#

Tags: f#

I've got this function, what I want to do is take a list, split every element in the list on '.' and place the separated elements in 2 different lists, my problem now is I'm getting an error that says the let expression is unfinished and I think it has to do with not having a return value, is there a way to bypass this or am I doing something completely wrong?

```
  let klist = []
  let olist = []
  let listSplit list = 
    match list.Split '.' with
    | [| x;y |] -> x :: klist, y :: olist
    | [| x |] -> x :: klist
    | _ -> None;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want something like

```
let listSplit (list: string list) = 
    let acc (kl, ol) = function
    | [| x; y |] -> (x::kl, y::ol)
    | [| x |] -> (x::kl, ol)

    list  |> List.map (fun s -> s.Split('.')) 
    |> List.filter(fun a -> a.Length = 1 || a.Length = 2)
    |> List.fold acc ([],[])
```

Your existing code has a few problems:

`list` has no split method. `String`s do have a `Split` method, so you probably want to split each string in the input list, which you can do with `List.map`.

Your `match` expression does not type check, and each branch has a different type - the first returns `string list * string list`, the second `string list` and the third `a' option`.

Comment: Great answer, but is there an easy way to split (string list * string list) into two separate string lists?

Comment: @Jacco - Yes you can use `List.unzip`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340249.aspx

Comment: Okay, any idea why I get this error from this code? "let asd (list : string list * string list) =
  let list1, list2 = List.unzip list" This expression was expected to have type
    ('a * 'b) list    
but here has type
    string list * string list

Comment: @Jacco - Sorry, I thought you wanted to split a `string * string list` into a pair of lists. You already have a pair of lists there so you have nothing to do. Alternatively you need to change the type of `list` to `(list : string * string list)`

Comment: So if (list : string * string list) already is a pair of lists, how do I for instance set a variable say x to the first list and y to the second list? Sorry for possibly stupid questions, very new to F# and functional programming in general

Comment: @Jacco - Sorry again, you actually need to declare the type of your list as `(string * string) list` since `string * string list` is the type of a pair whose first element is a `string` and second is a `string list`. If you do that then your previous code should work and you can say `let x, y = List.unzip list`.

Comment: Ahh, yes that's it! thanks alot for quick responses, really helpful.